# CSS image loading intermittently

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-2008

I can't provide much info except that sometimes (maybe 1 in every 25 runs) an image that I call with CSS does not load properly. The image is there because if I hover my mouse over it it shows in certain places.

The HTML:

```
<div class="body-top"> blah </div>
```

The CSS:

```
.body-top {background:url(../images/top.gif) no-repeat; height:55px; width: 970px; margin:0; padding:0;}
```

It is running on Visual Studio's Development Server.

Any ideas?

**edit**: hovering over the image itself actually doesn't make anything appear, it's when i hover over a link that is on the image

Comment: Are you previewing the page in Visual Studio or a real browser?

Comment: Can you post the header code, anchors and all?

Comment: lol @spud "real browser" and "IE" in the same sentence - try encapsulating your urls like this: `url('URL HERE')`

Comment: heh, it is what our customers use

Comment: Is the image transparent?  And have you tried with a different image?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to help without seeing the page, but.

Can you verify that none of the elements inside have a background colour?
Try adding this to test things:

```
.body-top *{background:none !important;}
```

Don't use this as final code, because the !important flag will stop any background working for elements inside .body-top